# Complexity of a list problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, discrete-optimization

I have two lists $L_1$ and $L_2$ of real numbers which are of equal length $n$ and I would like to analyze the complexity of the following problem:
Select an index set $I\subseteq \{1,...,n\}$ with minimum cardinality such that $$\sum_{i \in I}L_1(i)\geq c_1$$ and
$$\sum_{i \in I}L_2(i)\geq c_2$$ for two given constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.

The problem reminds me of some kind of subset sum problem but I can not find a reduction. I would be very grateful if someone could give me a hint for a reduction, a polynomial time algorithm or a dynamic programming approach for solving the problem.

Comment: Does your problem depend on the numbers being real numbers? Can they be natural numbers just as well?

Comment: The numbers can be natural as well. Solving the the problem with the numbers being natural would already help me a lot.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443595/dynamic-programming-multiple-subset-sum

Comment: Thanks! But might it be even possible that my problem is solvable in polynomial time, given that it involves inequality constraints, unlike the Subset Sum Problem which deals with equality constraints and is known to be NP-hard?

Comment: What's the matter with an algorithm where you choose the largest element of the list, then the next largest, and then the next largest after that, until the constant is reached or exceeded? Is there a counterexample to that?

Comment: This would of course work if there is only one list but the problem is that I have two lists and I want to choose a minimum index set which I apply to both lists (which is possible since they are of equal length) such that both constants are reached or exceeded.

Answer (score 1):

For a dynamic programming approach, let value function $V(k,b_1,b_2)$ denote the minimum cardinality of $I\subseteq\{1,\dots,k\}$ such that $\sum_{i\in I} L_1(i) \ge b_1$ and $\sum_{i\in I} L_2(i) \ge b_2$. We want to compute $V(n,c_1,c_2)$. The DP recursion is $$V(k,b_1,b_2)=\min(V(k-1,b_1,b_2),1+V(k-1,b_1-L_1(k),b_2-L_2(k)))$$